# Merge two array

Tags: php, arrays, merge

I have two arrays

```
Array
(
    [rows] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [color] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [color] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

and

```
Array
(
    [rows] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [kaka] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [kaka] => 1
                )

        )

)
```

i want to merge that array, so the output is

```
Array
(
    [rows] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [color] => 0,
                    [kaka] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [color] => 1,
                    [kaka] => 0
                )
        )
)
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: Have you tried a straightforward `foreach`?

Comment: what about `array_merge_recursive()` ?

Comment: i've tried array_merge_recursive and the result is :
Array
(
    [rows] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [color] => 0
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [color] => 1
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [kaka] => 0
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [kaka] => 1
                )

        )

)

Comment: Will the array be in this format? Or it can be undefined number of depth?

Comment: @Richard Moriz: but how about plain old `foreach`?

Comment: yes, the array must be in this format

Comment: @zerkms : I'll check for it now

Comment: thanks all for helping me :)

Comment: @Richard Moriz: you have learnt nothing from this though, have you?

Comment: yeah, you're right. I try so many times, but i didn't get the result what I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
$arr1 = array('row' => array(
                '0' => array ('color' => 0),
                '1' => array ('color' => 1)
              ));
$arr2 = array('row' => array(
                '0' => array ('kaka' => 0, 'dada' => 2),
                '1' => array ('kaka' => 1, 'tata' => 2),
                '2' => array ('kaka' => 2)
              ));

function merge($arr1, $arr2) {
    $result = $arr1;
    foreach($arr2['row'] as $key => $value) {
        foreach($value as $vkey => $vvalue) {
            $result['row'][$key][$vkey] = $vvalue;
        }
    }

    return $result;
}

$merge = merge($arr1, $arr2);
var_dump($merge);
```

Output

```
array (size=1)
  'row' => 
    array (size=3)
      0 => 
        array (size=3)
          'color' => int 0
          'kaka' => int 0
          'dada' => int 2
      1 => 
        array (size=3)
          'color' => int 1
          'kaka' => int 1
          'tata' => int 2
      2 => 
        array (size=1)
          'kaka' => int 2
```